# Can facebook og:image dynamically pull image from a specific div

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to tell the facebook metatag `og:image` to pull the image from a specific div instead of using the image source.

Example: have the og:image automatically pull the image inside of `#personal_page_image_div`?

```
<div class="tr-image-div" id="personal_page_image_div">
    <img src="../images/7237.1140778217.custom.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Why don't you modify the og tag to use that image?

Comment: Pages are creating by participants when they register for an event. Sometimes it is pulling the image the participant image that they upload but sometimes it is pulling the event logo. I can force it to pull the event logo but would prefer if it would use the image that they upload. I think it depends on the size of the image that they upload, whether or not it will be pulled or if it will default to the event logo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You could use javascript to get the image URL and add it in as `og:image`, but since this happens after page load, Facebook will not recognise it when fetching the `open graph` data.